# .post-text img.wp-smiley should not also have a margin-bottom: 14px property

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog

Smileys in posts look off because they also get the 14px margin at the bottom that's intended for normal images. Smileys however also have the wp-smiley class, so it should be possible to have them appear inline correctly.

If you're logged onto the blog you can see the problem in action [here.](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/?p=2706&preview=true) Otherwise see [here](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/08/15/stanley-parable/).

I could honestly do with turning automatic smileys off, but...

Comment: I'm all for disabling smiley's altogether. I hate smileys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've disabled smileys for now, the default ones look out of place in pretty much any theme of any WP blog ever.

I can't make a CSS fix if someone else decides to turn them back on in future though, since moving to SE I lost the power to edit themes.

<sup>shouldn't be an issue though because nobody will turn them back on... right?</sup>